# C++ string.length() Strange Behavior

Tags: c++, string, int

I just came across an extremely strange problem. The function I have is simply:

```
int strStr(string haystack, string needle) {

    for(int i=0; i<=(haystack.length()-needle.length()); i++){
        cout<<"i "<<i<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then if I call `strStr("", "a")`, although `haystack.length()-needle.length()=-1`, this will not return 0, you can try it yourself...

Comment: @aslg no, you can try size() too, same behavior.

Comment: @aslg According to the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size), they are not different.

Comment: Length and size are the same to my knowledge. `i=0; i <= -1; i++` gonna take a while to get to the exit case.

Comment: @user4581301  why take a while? shouldn't get into the loop at all

Comment: Because that -1 is an unsigned int.

Comment: Sorry about that. I should have just answered the question and not tried to be funny. That or be more obvious.

Comment: @Arch1tect One of the most common implementations of negative numbers ends up having negative numbers occupy the usual upper half of the bounds of an unsigned `int` or `int`-like variable, going in opposite order where -1 ends up being the highest value an unsigned number can take on. This is why, when you convert -1 to unsigned, it becomes the maximum value an unsigned number can hold. Note that compilers can catch this error if you pass, for example, `-Wall -Wextra` compilation flags and such for GCC/Clang whenever you compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `.length()` (and `.size()`) return `size_t`, which is an unsigned int. You think you get a negative number, when in fact it underflows back to the maximum value for `size_t` (On my machine, this is 18446744073709551615). This means your for loop will loop through all the possible values of size_t, instead of just exiting immediately like you expect.

To get the result you want, you can explicitly convert the sizes to `int`s, rather than `unsigned int`s (See aslgs answer), although this may fail for strings with sufficient length (Enough to over/under flow a standard `int`)

**Edit:** 
Two solutions from the comments below:

1. (Nir Friedman) Instead of using `int` as in aslg's answer, include the  header and use an int64_t, which will avoid the problem mentioned above.
2. (rici) Turn your for loop into `for(int i = 0;needle.length() + i <= haystack.length();i ++){`, which avoid the problem all together by rearranging the equation to avoid the subtraction all together.

Comment: int is not such a good recommendation for the reasons that you noted. On most architectures, int is only 32 bits. Instead, I'd recommend #including <cstdint> and using an int64_t, or a long long int (guaranteed at least 64 bits). This will work for all strings, unless your computer has 2^63 bytes of RAM.

Comment: Or avoid the issue by writing the condition as: `needle.length() + i <= haystack.length()`

Answer (score 1):

```
(haystack.length()-needle.length())
```

`length` returns a `size_t`, in other words an unsigned int. Given the size of your strings, 0 and 1 respectively, when you calculate the difference it underflows and becomes the maximum possible value for an unsigned int. (Which is approximately 4.2 billions for a storage of 4 bytes, but could be a different value)

```
i<=(haystack.length()-needle.length())
```

The indexer `i` is converted by the compiler into an unsigned int to match the type. So you're gonna have to wait until `i` is greater than the max possible value for an unsigned int. It's not going to stop.

Solution:

You have to convert the result of each method to int, like so,

```
i <= ( (int)haystack.length() - (int)needle.length() )
```